# Custom function to check the data type of each column

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyverse

I am creating a function that runs through my variables and determines if they are numeric. If the variable is numeric, I want it to print the mean, median, variance, mode and range. And if it is not numeric, I want it to print just the mode. However it doesn't work not sure if I am using the right function (typeof & class)

I receive below error

```
Error: Must group by variables found in `.data`.
* Column `col` is not found.
```

My try (Function)

```
myfun <- function(df,col) {

  print(typeof(df[,col]))
   if(class(df$col)=="numeric"){
     mean=mean(df$col)
     median=median(df$col)
     variance=var(df$col)
     mode =mode(df$col)
     range=range(df$col)
     df <- data.frame(mean=mean,median=median,variance=variance,mode=mode,range=range)
   } else df=count(df,col,sort=TRUE)[1,1]
     print(max_count)
 }

myfun(iris,"Species")
myfun(iris,"Sepal.Length")
```

Comment: I guess you want to use `count(df,!!col,sort=TRUE)`. I recommend reading [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `$` inside functions, we can use `[[` to extract a particular columns.

You can modify the function as follows -

```
myfun <- function(df,col) {

  if(is.numeric(df[[col]])) {
    list(mean=mean(df[[col]]),
         median=median(df[[col]]),
         variance = var(df[[col]]),
         mode = Mode(df[[col]]),
         range=range(df[[col]]))
  } else list(mode = Mode(df[[col]]))
}


Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

myfun(iris,"Species")

#$mode
#[1] setosa
#Levels: setosa versicolor virginica

myfun(iris,"Sepal.Length")
#$mean
#[1] 5.843333

#$median
#[1] 5.8

#$variance
#[1] 0.6856935

#$mode
#[1] 5

#$range
#[1] 4.3 7.9
```

Comment: Don't use $ inside functions, we can use [[ to extract a particular columns.

Just the advice I needed. Thanks